# Python Sphinx with multiple modules with the same structure

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

I have a folder structure as:

```
folder
  foo
    src
      __init__.py
      folder1
        __init__.py
        fileA.py
        fileB.py
  bar
    src
      __init__.py
      folder1
        __init__.py
        fileA.py
        fileB.py
```

and in the code in fileA I import something like:
`from src.folder1.fileA import something`

When I try to document these files one of the modules is not imported.

in `conf.py`:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../folder/foo/'))
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.abspath('../../folder/bar/'))
```

The only way to show something in the HTML page is using:

```
.. automodule:: src.folder1.fileB
```

but when I run make only the description of one function is showed to both foo and bar in the html page.

Is there any change to make on docs to don't change the imports in code?

Comment: "one of the modules is not imported" - which module? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mzjn the only module that appears in sphinx html page is foo or bar, it depends of nothing, just happens. I've document fileB with a different function name and description in foo and bar and then appears 'foo' in both html pages or 'bar' in both.

Comment: What is the purpose of this directory structure? You have two packages called `src` with exactly the same structure. The last one that is imported "wins", as far as I can tell.

Comment: @mzjn It is a solution for data workflow. Foo and Bar are independent jobs and there is a manager that orchestrates everything.

Comment: Why does it have to be this way just because it is a "data workflow" with a "manager"? I don't know what that means.

Comment: @mzjn It is a full project. A service that runs like a manager and orchestrates all independent jobs. Foo and Bar are independent jobs. The repository is designed as the folder structure above